# Call asp.net webservice from MVC 4 view

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to call an asp.net webservice in an MVC web application. I just upgraded the project from MVC 1 to MVC 4, everything is working fine except the calling of services that previously worked in the MVC 1 application. The problem is that I am getting a "404 not found" error. Its not even hitting the function.

The code I am using to call the service and function is shown below.

```
function RunAsync(url, jsondata, success, error) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: jsondata,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(result.d);
            if (obj.Status == 'Success') {
                eval(success + '(obj)');
            }
            else if ((error != null) && (obj.Status == 'Error')) {
                eval(error + '(obj)');
            }
            else {
                alert(obj.Message);
            }
        },
        error: function(request, status, throwerror) {
            var message = '';
            message += 'The request could not complete.';
            message += '<br />' + 'Request status:' + request.status;
            message += '<br />' + 'Request response:' + request.responseText;
            window.open('', 'exception').document.write(message);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm really stumped on this one.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide function arguments here?

Comment: By: "It's not even hitting the function", do you mean that none of this javascript is being run?

Comment: @jwddixonThe javascript is being run, but its not getting to the function in the service. Thus, the 404 error.

Comment: What is the URL in your Ajax Call? and is this on your local machine or on your server?

Comment: @HaBo this is running on my local machine. The site is still in its dev phase so haven't tested on a live domain. The URL is http://localhost:37194/Services/Admin/PageLookupService.asmx/FetchPagesByType. I am also passing 2 arguments to it, language and type.

Comment: I just tested on a live domain and its working flawlessly. I'm confused as to why it wouldn't work in a dev environment then.

Comment: all I can say is, your web service not hosted well to be consumed on local

Comment: By "hosted well" I'm assuming you think that it is separate from the project and hosted on a server somewhere. It is an internal .asmx service which should be accessible locally anyway. I can't understand how it works locally with MVC 1, and on the live site, but not locally with MVC 4.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this a couple weeks ago and found that IIS wasn't serving up my service requests.  The fix was to reregister the services in IIS with the following:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.net\framework\v3.0\WindowsCommunicationFoundation\servicemodelreg -i
```

I believe you have to run this "as Administrator".

Comment: I'm assuming I have to run this in CMD Prompt? The thing is this is happening through the source. I haven't checked the live version yet, but I will assume its doing the same.

Comment: Yes, launch your cmd prompt as administrator.